# AppEngine frontend to DB latency temporarily ~10 secs every ~20 calls?

Tags: java, google-app-engine

This (see chart below) is happening since 3/7. 
Sure this can be because of instances loading and unloading.
But do you know other reasons for GAE behaving like this?

It's not a high replication instance. And during testing we had up to 5 instances F2 running with only our test client calls. There basically are DB calls, image processing and memcache usage.

There are already 2 issues which look equal:
http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=4180&sort=priority&colspec=ID%20Type%20Component%20Status%20Stars%20Summary%20Language%20Priority%20Owner%20Log

http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=6309&sort=priority&colspec=ID%20Type%20Component%20Status%20Stars%20Summary%20Language%20Priority%20Owner%20Log

And there's an entry in the forum:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-appengine/js5CeRWLQZ0/discussion

[image: GAE-J Appstat Chart]

Logging (Shay requested) shows that Persistence Manager seems to take 6 seconds to initialize:

```
2012-03-11 15:32:47.543 /api/yyy 200 16811ms 0kb xxx/1.1 CFNetwork/548.1.4 Darwin/11.0.0
78.53.230.114 - - [11/Mar/2012:07:32:47 -0700] "POST /api/yyy HTTP/1.1" 200 94 - "zzz/1.1 CFNetwork/548.1.4 Darwin/11.0.0" "zzz.appspot.com" ms=16812 cpu_ms=6040 api_cpu_ms=82 cpm_usd=0.167820 pending_ms=5765 instance=00c71b117ca3858c47bdc41d5b30a732dd76eaaf
I 2012-03-11 15:32:37.196
www.server.xxxServlet getvvv: 1
I 2012-03-11 15:32:37.202
www.server.xxxServlet getvvv: hash
I 2012-03-11 15:32:37.207
www.server.xxxServlet getvvv: get PM (PersistenceManager pm = PMF.get().getPersistenceManager();)
I 2012-03-11 15:32:43.606
www.server.xxxServlet getvvv: get data
I 2012-03-11 15:32:47.355
www.server.xxxServlet getvvv: got data
I 2012-03-11 15:32:47.388
www.server.xxxServlet getvvv: done
```

and PMF is implemented as:

```
public final class PMF {
    private static final PersistenceManagerFactory pmfInstance =
        JDOHelper.getPersistenceManagerFactory("transactions-optional");

    private PMF() {}

    public static PersistenceManagerFactory get() {
        return pmfInstance;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The area where you don't see any stats is usually your code running, the stats starts when the request is entered I don't think this got any thing to do with instance loading.
I suggest adding logs to see the flow of your handler code.

Comment: I added an example log and info regarding persistence manager to the question above.

Answer (score 0):

Ikai Lan replied in the forum google-appengine.googlegroups.com:

"Given that the SLA applies to HRD and not master/slave applications, you are definitely going to get a better quality of service migrating to HRD. In fact, I strongly advise that you do so."

"With master/slave applications, we do what we can to address the short term symptoms as well as the underlying system issues without impacting serving,..."

"We may be announcing a maintenance in the very near future that will impact the serving of master/slave applications."

Link:
https://groups.google.com/d/msg/google-appengine/js5CeRWLQZ0/4mFqPWJQjSoJ

For me this means there currently are issues with GAE master/slave and a maintenance announcement was announced.